# Display tags from list of separated comma words

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list of tags stores in a table, when I call this list by `<td>{{article.tags}} </td> flask code`, the display is basic as follows (tag1, tag2, tag3 ..), I want to display them as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTtpG.png) 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Jinja2 for loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#for):

```
{% for tag in article.tags.split(',') %}
    <td>{{ tag }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have integrated your code, but I receive separate words as follows:
( W o r d s, t e s t ) in tags .